# Why is my span textarea bigger then the characters itself

Tags: cursor, textarea, jquery-ui-selectable

When marking a character of this h1 (consists of spans with the letters) the area is bigger than the character itself which leads to the text selection cursor before the character is even selected. Wouldn't be an issue for me but there will be images randomly generated on the site with a lightbox and i need to select the images behind  or next to the text [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxDmG.png).

I tried changing to display: inline-block on the span and changing the line-height did not make a difference.